# What is the name of the "can't be targeted by spells or hero power" ability?

Tags: hearthstone

There are several cards, such as Arcane Nullifier, Spectral Knight, and Faerie Dragon that have the card text "cannot be targeted by spells or hero power". I haven't been able to find an "official" term for this ability online. Is there an official or unofficially accepted name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is none as of yet. There's been debate in the HS community about several options. Veil being my personal favorite, but nothing mentioned by Blizzard as of yet. If there was an official name, it would be on the cards, no?

[Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/2o2lr3/i_think_its_time_we_got_a_name_for_the_cannot_be/) is some discussion on it.

Comment: So there is no generally accepted term?

Comment: Nopes. I added a link to one of the threads I recalled. Spealth was brought up as a joke. Stealth from Spells. Spealth.

Comment: Definitely shroud.

Comment: Shroud is already taken by MtG, as several people pointed out.

Comment: Okay, I'm just gonna call it shroud

Comment: Avoiding all terms used up by MtG would be nearly impossible though once they add a few more mechanics (which is bound to happen, especially flying is an obvious future inclusion), since they have so many mechanics by now. And tap is the only trademarked one as far as I know. So there's really not much of a (legal) problem with *Shroud*. My vote definitely goes to *Spealth* though :D It also shares a similar animation, basically just gold instead of grey. I can also see stealing *Hexproof* happening or altering it to *Spellproof*, *Spellshield* or something similar.